# Saving a Word doc as a hi res pdf

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I am trying to save a Word doc in the font AT Citadel to a hi res pdf for hi quality output. My pdf is translating to a lo res font when output on a high quality copier. I am using Word 2007. Any suggestions how how to save this file to a hi res pdf?

Comment: Could you tell us the steps in the process you are using to make the PDF?  Are you generating it from Word directly or printing to a PDF printer driver?

Comment: What @cxw said. Also, if you're using the Save as PDF and XPS feature/add-on, are you optimising for printing (standard size) or online publishing (minimum size)?

Comment: Also, what type of font is it? Ttf otf? Do you have to print as pdf? Printing directly from Word may be better in this instance so long as the machine printing has the font or it's a ttf font that can be and has been embedded in the doc.

Comment: It is a ttf font, AT Citadel. I saved it as a pdf in Word checking off Standard (publishing online and printing). I selected PDF Options - ISO 19905-1 compliant (PDF/A). Some of the flourishes are cut off and the letters are not sharp.    I also tried to print to Nitro PDF Creator (Pro 8). In options I tried with and without the fonts embedded. Nothing works. The letters are not sharp. I think it is saving it as 300 dpi. I have office 2007 and windows 8. Any further thoughts. Thanks for the help and suggestions.